# How to convert 1k, 3k, 7m, 10m, 10.2m or any formatted value into numbers using java script

Tags: javascript, function

I want o convert formatted currency values like:
`1m`
`2m`
`3.789m`
`100k`
`20k`
`80.5b`
etc.
into pure numbers using java script how can we achieve that?

Comment: parse the numeric value, then multiply by a factor that depends on the letter

Comment: parseFloat to get the number ... and string.at(-1) to get the letter ... then it's easy - `const fn=s=>parseFloat(s)*{k:1_000,m:1_000_000,b:1_000_000_000}[s.at(-1)]??1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good question (I'm sure someone in the comments will tell you that too), but I'm bored so I'll give you the code. Here it is:

```js
function convSuffix(str) {
  const suffix = str[str.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if (!isNaN(parseInt(suffix))) return parseInt(str);
  // If you want to allow decimials in the result, then use this 
  // instead of the previous line:
  // if (!isNaN(parseInt(suffix))) return parseFloat(str);
  
  const num = parseFloat(str.slice(0, str.length-1));
  if (suffix === 'k') return num * 1000;
  else if (suffix === 'm') return num * 1000000;
  else if (suffix === 'b') return num * 1000000000;
  else return NaN;
}

console.log(convSuffix("14")) // => 14
console.log(convSuffix("1.34b")) // => 1340000000
console.log(convSuffix("2K")) // => 2000
console.log(convSuffix("7.2m")) // => 7200000
console.log(convSuffix("7.8")) // => 7
```

You can add more suffixes as you see fit. If there is no suffix, it returns the value, and if it matches no suffix it returns `NaN`.

Comment: `convSuffix("1.23")` results in `1` - just sayin :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes. OP said it was for a discord bot, so I assumed only whole numbers. However, if decimals are needed too, then one just needs to change the first `parseInt()` to `parseFloat()`. I've added comment in the code.

Comment: as I said, I was just sayin, but makes perfect sense - OP never *said* it was for a discord bot though - I never trust newbie tags :p

Comment: thanks also i need it for some logic in my discord bot